# Extracting multiple value in Jmeter using regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

In my script i am using multiple(almost 10) regular expressions to extract values,my question here is that would it impact on response time if so could anyone explain me how is it impacting.

Comment: depends on the regular expressions you are using..

Comment: Please clarify what "response time" you are taking about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple answer would be.. it depends on the regexes you are using and the amount of data you are working on.

Regex engine parses the input string by attempting all permutations at every character, even backtracking in some cases. This (the number of steps taken to match) is proportional to the size of the string you are using.

So, Yes.. it would affect your regex performance.. but not the response time of itself.

Comment: i am using simple regex to extract product name,price etc

Comment: This answer does not make sense. Response time in the context of JMeter means the time to receive a response from the server. Regex extractions are typically run after the response is received, and the regex does not affect the server response time whatsoever.

Comment: @RaGe you are right.. the response time of a server does not depend on the regex performance.. but what if the overall response time depends on the performance? Example.. I am using regex to parse the input string before sending request to the server.. In this case... the overall response time differs and my answer makes some sense.. If it was just the response time of the server.. question itself wont make sense.. :)

Comment: Still does not make sense. The clock starts when the request is sent to the server and clock stops when the last byte of the response is received from the server. Any pre-calculations and post-calculations do not play into the measured server response time.

Comment: @RaGe seems.. you dint get my point.. I explained the same thing.. According to OP...

Comment: Agree with RaGe, Your answer doesn't make any sense. response time is counted as time between when request is sent and when response was received. postprocessing or preprocessing time is not included in response time (neither overall nor per req.) That additional processing time should not be considered as it is very less(microseconds or milliseconds) as compared to response time (milliseconds to seconds)